# Problems with localbitcoins api pagination on nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, pagination

I'm developing with the LocalBitcoins API using nodejs. Heres the code

```
const adsList = async (action, options = {}, page) => {
    let prefix = action + '-'

    let countryCode = (options.countryCode) ? options.countryCode : false
    let countryName = (options.countryName) ? options.countryName : false
    let paymentMethod = (options.paymentMethod) ? options.paymentMethod : false
    let currency = (options.currency) ? options.currency : false

    let basePath = prefix + 'bitcoins-online'
    let suffix = (page > 1) ? `.json?page=2` : '.json'

    let path

    if (currency) {
        path = (paymentMethod) ? `${basePath}/${currency}/${paymentMethod}/${suffix}` : `${basePath}/${currency}/${suffix}`
    } else if (countryCode && countryName) {
        path = (paymentMethod) ? `${basePath}/${countryCode}/${countryName}/${paymentMethod}/${suffix}` : `${basePath}/${countryCode}/${countryName}/${suffix}`
    } else if (!currency && !countryCode && !countryName) {
        path = (paymentMethod) ? `${basePath}/${paymentMethod}/${suffix}` : `${basePath}/${suffix}`
    }

    let response = await get(path, true)

    return response
}
```

Now when I make a call with no page given, everything works fine.

```
adsList('sell', {
  countryCode: 'co',
  countryName: 'colombia'
}).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

The output:

```
{
  pagination: {
    next: 'https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/co/colombia/.json?page=2'
  },
  data: {
    ad_list: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    ad_count: 50
  }
}
```

Ah, but when I add a page:

```
adsList('sell', {
  countryCode: 'co',
  countryName: 'colombia'
}, 2).then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

This is the output:

```
{
  error: {
    message: 'HMAC authentication key and signature was given, but they are invalid.',
    error_code: 41
  }
}
```

I have been working on this for hours but and searching info but there is nothing, so if you have any solution I will be grateful.

Comment: You can confirm two things. First, `console.log` `page` and make sure it's passed correctly. Second, before making the API call, `console.log` your `path` and compare the two. And try to call it directly (via your browser or Postman) and make sure it returns expected response.

Comment: I did. When I console.log page it returns 2 as expected, and the path equals the path in response.pagination.next.

Comment: ok good. did you try to call that directly through your browser? put that path in your browser address bar and see the response.

Comment: Yeah. It works https://localbitcoins.com/sell-bitcoins-online/co/colombia/.json?page=2

Comment: BTW I opened the link from the terminal, the one I got when I made the console.log